# Azure Data Factory - Set metadata of blob container along with 'Copy' Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have built a pipeline in Azure Data Factory that calls a web api using http connector(linked service to http connector) and store the data in Azure container(linked service to ADLS gen2) using Copy activity. Is there any way by which we can save/write to the metadata for the blob container inside copy activity or using some other activity in ADF? If the api call is successful and when file is saved to container, I need to write the starttime of the pipeline as a metadata to the blob container.

Thanks & Regards,
Kesavan.

Comment: Hi @Kesavan, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should do that with [Azure Function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity).

The general process should be like this:

1. As we know, we can get some properties of the running pipeline. We can see the output of the Copy activity in ADF. The start attribute is the start time of the activity, we can get it via `@{activity('<Activity_Name>').output.executionDetails[0].start}`.
   [image]
2. Then we can use Azure function activity and pass the value to the backend function via Headers or body(POST request).
   [image]

3.First, we need create a [C# function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp). We can parse the parameters of Heards or body(POST request) in the HTTP request. According to [Manage blob properties and metadata with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata?tabs=dotnet), we can use the **SetMetadataAsync** method of the **BlobClient** class to set Bolb metadata.

The pseudo code is as follows:

```cs
public static async Task AddBlobMetadataAsync(BlobClient blob)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Adding blob metadata...");

    try
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> metadata =
           new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // Add metadata to the dictionary by calling the Add method
        metadata.Add("startTime", startTime);


        // Set the blob's metadata.
        await blob.SetMetadataAsync(metadata);
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"HTTP error code {e.Status}: {e.ErrorCode}");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[BlobClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet)

Answer (score 0):

Update (Actually answering the question now):

**For setting Metadata on a Azure Storage Account Container you can do the following in Azure Data Factory (Ensure your ADF has proper access to the Storage Account or Container first, Contributor should work):**

[image: HTTP ADF Example]

**Here is the exact JSON code for the Web Activity, I have scrubbed storage account name from the request:**

```
{
"name": "Web1_copy1",
"type": "WebActivity",
"dependsOn": [],
"policy": {
    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
    "retry": 0,
    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
    "secureOutput": false,
    "secureInput": false
},
"userProperties": [],
"typeProperties": {
    "url": {
        "value": "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/blob-edw-testfiles?restype=container&comp=metadata",
        "type": "Expression"
    },
    "method": "PUT",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Date": {
            "value": "@formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')",
            "type": "Expression"
        },
        "x-ms-version": "2019-07-07",
        "x-ms-meta-NameOfMetadataKey": "This Is My Metadata Value"
    },
    "body": {
        "value": "@toLower('{}')",
        "type": "Expression"
    },
    "disableCertValidation": true,
    "authentication": {
        "type": "MSI",
        "resource": {
            "value": "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net",
            "type": "Expression"
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Proof that it works:**
[image: It Works]

---

**For Setting Metadata on a Blob in a copy activity you can do the following (This is for a Blob, not a container!):**

[image: Set Metadata in Copy Activity]

Comment: I should mention, you can also use an Azure Function or Azure Blob REST API, but not necessary anymore.

Comment: This is very useful, but if you have more files and you need some extra logic to decided what the value of the metadata property should be, then an Azure function should be used?

Comment: You can use dynamic content to specify the name of the key and the value. But it appears like you have to specify up front how many keys you will have, then you could dynamically generate what the values of the Key Name and Value are. If you are trying to get extremely complex with it, then it could be that an Azure Function or REST API would need to do the set metadata, but I think this ADF Native Functionality should work in 90% of situations.

Comment: This does not appear to set the metadata on the folder or container, only on the blobs. Reading the original question, it was about setting metadata on the container.

Comment: Ah you are right, that's my bad. I will update the answer to show how you can set the Metadata on the Container straight from ADF without having to build an Azure Function.